# Cloud Tasks Not Triggering HTTPrequest Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-tasks-api

I have one simple cloud task queue and have successfully submitted a task to the queue. It is supposed to deliver a JSON payload to my API to perform a basic database update. The task is created at the end of a process in a .net core 3.1 app running locally on my desktop triggered by postman and the API is a golang app running in cloud run. However, the task never seems to fire and never registers an error.

The tasks in queue is always 0 and the tasks running is always blank. I have hit the "Run Now" button dozens of times but it never changes anything and no log entries or failed attempts are ever registered.

The task is created with the OIDCToken with a service account and audience set for the service account that has the authorization to create tokens and execute the cloud run instance.

[Screen Shot of Tasks Queue in Google Cloud Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TC99.png)

Task creation log entry shows that it was created OK:

```
{
  "insertId": "efq7sxb14",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "taskCreationLog": {
      "targetAddress": "PUT https://{readacted}",
      "targetType": "HTTP",
      "scheduleTime": "2020-04-25T01:15:48.434808Z",
      "status": "OK"
    },
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog",
    "task": "projects/{readacted}/locations/us-central1/queues/database-updates/tasks/0998892809207251757"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_tasks_queue",
    "labels": {
      "target_type": "HTTP",
      "project_id": "{readacted}",
      "queue_id": "database-updates"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-04-25T01:15:48.435878120Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/{readacted}/logs/cloudtasks.googleapis.com%2Ftask_operations_log",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-04-25T01:15:49.469544393Z"
}
```

Any ideas as to why the tasks are not running? This is my first time using Cloud Tasks so don't rule out the idiot between the keyboard and the chair.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be using a non-default service. See [Configuring Cloud Tasks queues](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues)

Try creating a task from the command line and watch the logs e.g.

```
gcloud tasks create-app-engine-task --queue=default \
--method=POST --relative-uri=/update_counter --routing=service:worker \
--body-content=10
```

In my own case, I used `--routing=service:api` and it worked straight away. Then I added AppEngineRouting to the AppEngineHttpRequest.